# How can I reset to the factory settings?

Tags: sd-card, settings

I was playing around with my Raspberry Pi and I accidentally bricked it! How can I restore it back to the factory defaults?

Comment: Try reformatting the SD card and re-installing the operating system on the SD card.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can reset the device to factory defaults by reflashing the SD card.

You can find advice on how to do this here: [How do I install an OS image onto an SD card?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/931/86).

Answer (score 9):

Bricking a device usually refers to getting the ROM into a corrupted state, by flashing with a bad ROM or a failed flash. As Pi has no ROM, you can't brick it like that. Pi runs off the SD card only, so a clean reflash of the SD card should fix it.

If a particuar card is not working (and has never worked) there is a list of known problem cards on a wiki: http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#Problem_SD_Cards

Answer (score 0):

Try reformatting the SD card and reinstalling the new operating system on the SD card then install onto your Raspberry Pi.