# How can I remove all data from my Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: software-development

Recently I tried downloading a full Bitcoin node, but I keep receiving an error before I can run the command `bitcoind`.

What command should I use to start the entire Pi over from scratch?

Comment: Try reading error messages and fixing the actual error before resorting to your slash-and-burn tactic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reset to the factory settings?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/154/how-can-i-reset-to-the-factory-settings)

Answer (score 1):

All data is held on the SD card.

If you write a fresh (for instance Raspbian) image to the SD card that will remove all existing data.